# Magento 1.9.3 additional information under details

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, additional-information, product-tab

On the product view page the additional information is next the details. (tabs)

I want the additional information under the details.

So:
Details
Additional information
Review

Answer (score 0):

Go to `local.xml` then update this block

```
<catalog_product_view>
   ...
   <reference name="product.info">
       /*-->*/ <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
   </reference>
   ...
</catalog_product_view>
```

like this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" after="-"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean with /place it after the block that you want
   </reference>  I placed the info in local.xml but nothing happend.

Comment: No, look my update please, dont forget to clear cache

Answer (score 0):

I did not had a local.xml file  so I make one :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * local.xml
 *
 * Local layout modifications for our local theme
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     my_theme_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2011 Magebase.
 */
-->
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view>
   <reference name="product.info">
      <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" after="description"/>
   </reference>
</catalog_product_view>

</layout> 


The problem is that the attributes disapeared
```